# Android 4.2.2 alternative webview

Tags: android, webview

I'm working on a custom Android device running Android 4.2.2.

We have a lot of troubles with the default webkit webview not behaving as it should (Failing some javascript etc.) and performing very poorly.

All these issues are fixed on our phones webview running on Android 4.4.

Is there an alternative way to use the new chromium backed webview from Android 4.4 on my 4.2.2 build ? (I'm building AOSP 4.2.2 from source)

If not, is there some alternative webview that I could test, which perhaps fixes some/most of our javascript/performance issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on this project: https://github.com/examplecode/chromium_android_webview. Also here is similar discussion in google group: [Use the Chromium web view to replace the default android webview (<4.4)](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/ikonNIwbOkw)

Comment: Do you have any experience with crosswalk? https://gist.github.com/butelo/9365587 seems to do a lot of what I'm requesting.

Comment: I used crosswalk on these projects: https://01.org/html5webapps/webapps - it worked pretty nicely.