# WebView in android wear is giving errors when running

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview, wear-os

I am trying to make a web browser for android wear and I am using android studio. My code for the inflating.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
           webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
            //this will set javascript enabled.
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            //loading url to google.com
            webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");

            webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

The full error is below:

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:57)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.inflate(WatchViewStub.java:131)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.onMeasure(WatchViewStub.java:141)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2338)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1145)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1340)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1032)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5657)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:57)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.inflate(WatchViewStub.java:131)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.onMeasure(WatchViewStub.java:141)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2338)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1145)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1340)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1032)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5657)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
            at com.android.webview.nullwebview.NullWebViewFactoryProvider.createWebView(NullWebViewFactoryProvider.java:41)
            at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2062)
            at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2120)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3461)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3517)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
            at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:52)
            at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:498)
            at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:475)
            at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:455)
            at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:444)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:57)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.inflate(WatchViewStub.java:131)
            at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.onMeasure(WatchViewStub.java:141)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2338)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1145)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1340)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1032)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5657)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have put in my xml the proper id as wvBrowser and I have the user permission in my android Manifest xml file. Does anybody know the problem?

Comment: as per you say your id is wvBrowser and in code you add something else.check it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use WebView on a wearable, check the list of unavailable features here: 
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html

Also, you can't connect to the internet directly from a wearable device, it doesn't have an internet access and can only receive data from the companion handheld.

EDIT:
Actually, I see only one way to do it:

1. Load an html page on a handheld and transfer it to a wearable using Wearable.DataApi
2. Display the page on a wearable using(may be customized) a third-party html library. May be the project from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25666998/2548988) will be useful here.

Comment: Well, is there anyway I could display a page like www.google.com because I know apps out there on the google play that load pages and are for android wear.

Comment: Can I use webview directly  without connecting with handheld device If i use android wear 2.0

Comment: from android wear 2.0 on wards,we can connect to internet directly right?

Comment: At this time, there is at least a way to determine if WebView is available on a device.  This link explains that, and also says WebView is not available on Wear OS:
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/managing-webview