# WebView support for android wear

Tags: android, webview, wear-os

Is there any way to display the `WebView`(Payment gateway page in particular) in android wear? I have done some investigations and wear doesn't seem to support it as of now.

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665445/webview-in-android-wear-is-giving-errors-when-running)

[link2](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/android-l-google-io-web-developers-chrome)

According to answers in the above link, I need to load the `WebView` in phone and send the rendered image to the Watch. But user won't be able to enter anything in `webview` input filelds. Is there anyway to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean like displaying a screenshot of your handheld's WebView on the smartwatch ? Well, do that, take a screenshot, send it to the wearable with the `DataApi` and display it on the wearable.

Comment: @Snow Yeah.. But is there any way for user to enter text in web view text fields in the wearable itself?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there is no WebView support on Android Wear

Comment: @Snow Oh ok:( Thanks! Hope they include `WebView` in wearable soon.

Comment: I don't think they will anytime soon, given the lack of input method except voice, I don't know how you can manage to use a webapp on it :/

Comment: @AbhishekV Did you get a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

[As specified here by Google](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html), the `android.webkit` API isn't supported in Android Wear.

Moreover, what you're trying to achieve seems **wrong**. There is no way a user will ever manage or want to enter its credit card (or other) credentials from a smartwatch. Remember that there is no (official) keyboard on Android Wear ! The only inputs are gestures and voice.

Google probably discarded the webkit API to avoid seeing such things in Wear apps ;)

Comment: Makes sense. But google could provide it's own keyboard in future updates and if the credit card details are already saved in pg, it's not that difficult for user to enter just the password.

Comment: That WebView does not exist on Wear OS is stated here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/managing-webview
It also shows how to determine if WebView is available on the device.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually reach that goal! Not sure on what was the strategy used but there's a fully working browser on Android Wear https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appfour.wearbrowser

Comment: Thanks for the info. Seems like it works! Need to investigate more on this.

Comment: Well, @AbhishekV - did you investigate? any insights?

Comment: Nope. I haven't investigated about it yet!

Comment: @AbhishekV have you investigated now..?

Answer (score -1):

You can do by following below link. I have done,It is working for me.

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/embedding_crosswalk_rvw.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20011165)

Comment: Sure.Refer  to this link for further info  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831156/my-app-not-able-to-find-a-crosswalk-dependency-and-r-file

Comment: crosswalk-project.org is unavailable.