# My app not able to find a crosswalk dependency and R file

Tags: android, crosswalk, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk-project

I have followed this link https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/embedding_crosswalk_rvw.html  to embed crosswalk in my android project.When I try to install,my app is crashing with below er

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/xwalk/core/R$string;
```

[image: My activity code looks exactly like this]

I've double-checked the dependencies from the gradle file. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I have imported .jar crosstalk file  as module project in my app.after that I have tried with .aar file(xwalk_core_library-23.53.589.4.aar) which i got from this link

https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/23.53.589.4/

Not it is working fine